# How ignore NullNode for deserialization JSON in JAVA

Tags: java, jackson

So the problem is the next:
I have POJO like:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class TestPOJO {

  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private JsonNode jsonNode;
```

Also I have json like

```
{
   "id":1
   "name": "foo"
   "jsonNode":null
}
```

When I try deserialize the last one by the

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
TestPOJO testPojo = objectMapper.readValue(<json String>, TestPOJO.class);
```

I get `testPojo` object where `jsonNode` field is `NullNode`, but I need in `testPojo == null`
How I can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)`?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: try with mapper  object `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);`

Comment: I've set it in ```@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)``` annotation and it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class that extends `JsonDeserializer<JsonNode>` and that returns null if `parser.getText()` is null:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonNodeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<JsonNode> {

    @Override
    public JsonNode deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException {
        String value = parser.getText();
        if(value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return (JsonNode) context.findRootValueDeserializer(context.constructType(JsonNode.class)).deserialize(parser, context);
    }
}
```

Then annotate the `jsonNode` attribute with `@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonNodeDeserializer.class)` to tell Jackson to use your custom deserializer:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class TestPOJO {

  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonNodeDeserializer.class)
  private JsonNode jsonNode;

  // getters and setters
}
```